# Structure inside structure in C (Linked List)

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that would allow me to print Teachers with their info by order including students id's. For example: when I try to run the program, the output would be something similar to this:

```
Teacher Apple, Age 55:
Student ID: 77
Student ID: 5456
Student ID: 4729
Student ID: 3784

Teacher bob, Age 67:
Student ID: 477
Student ID: 546
Student ID: 429
Student ID: 784
```

.. and so on.

However, I couldn't think of a way to print them in right format. I'm having trouble with nested loops.
here is my code :

```
struct Teacher {

    char* name;
    int age;
    struct Student* stds;
    struct Teacher* next;
};

struct Student 
{
    int id;
    struct Student* next;
};


int main() {

    //aray to store teachers' names
    char names[3][10] = { "first", "second", "third" };
//their age
    int age[3] = { 1,2,3 };
//students' id
    int id[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
//alocate the linkedlist in mem
    struct Teacher* head = (struct Teacher*)malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
    struct Student* headstd = (struct Student*)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    
    
    head->next = NULL;
    headstd->next = NULL;
    //head ->next = (struct Teacher*)malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
//adding temporary head and modefied it so I don't touch the actual head 
    struct Teacher* temhead = (struct Teacher*)malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
    struct Student* stdhead = (struct Student*)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    //head->name = 
    //(char)first.name ="first";
    temhead->next = NULL;
    stdhead->next = NULL;
///loop thorough the teachers
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
//loop through the students 
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            stdhead->next = (struct Student*)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
            stdhead = stdhead->next;
            stdhead->id = *(id + j);
            //temhead->age = 44;
            
            printf("Student ID: %d \n ", stdhead->id);
        }
//here after it goes through the students, it goes through teachers 
        temhead->next = (struct Teacher*)malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
        temhead = temhead->next;
//here I assigned the name of teachers to the array I have implementd @ first (names[3][10]
        temhead->name = *(names + i);
//print names (for now "first, second, ..")
        printf("node: %s \n ", temhead->name);

    }
//
//  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
//      temhead->next = (struct Teacher*)malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
//      //temhead->stds = (struct Teacher*)malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
//      temhead = temhead->next;
//      temhead->age = *(age + i);
//      //temhead->age = 44;
//      printf("%d \n ", temhead->age);
//
//  }
//
//  
//}
```

I just started learning C and I would Really Appreciate any help.
My outputs look like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of `stdhead` exactly? Don't all students get attached to teachers?

Comment: It's hard to help you because the code has no comments and you don't explain how you want the code to work. For example, you allocate a `Teacher` and make `head` point to it. But there are no comments. Is that supposed to be the first `Teacher`? Or is that a sentinel just to mark the beginning of the list? You never set a name for any `Teacher`, so how would code to print the names work even if you had it?

Comment: Please post a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Additionally, include the output directly in your question.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I edit it and add some comments.

Answer (score 1):

The print code would likely look something like this. But it won't work unless you assemble the teachers and students correctly in the first place.

```
for (struct Teacher *t = head; t != NULL; t = t->next)
{
    printf("Teacher %s, Age %d:\n", t->name, t->age);
    for (struct Student *s = t->stds; s != NULL; s = s->next)
        printf("Student ID: %d\n", s->id);
}
```

In order to assemble these lists, you probably want to write some functions to create a teacher and add it to the list and to add students to a teacher. Then call those functions to assemble the list in the first place.